# How to install and setup an item filter for Diablo 2 Single Player Plugy?

Tags: diablo-ii

I have installed Diablo II 1.12 and then D2SE, which allows me to play my single player game with Plugy (I play on version 1.13c). Now I want to add an item filter. I've found this reddit post
https://www.reddit.com/r/slashdiablo/comments/3b8zp7/new_bh_link/ with the BH Item Filter / Map Hack from the slashdiablo guys. I took a suggested config and loaded it in and it seems to work. Still I'm not completely sure how that thing works or if the weird things I experiece are just bugs (f.e. I thought that I filtered all potions below super out, but sometimes they still appear). I would like to have an item filter without bugs and a documentation and help to set it up. My goal is basically this:

Leave the game as it is, but filter out Gold<5000, filter out all Health/Mana/Reg potions below super, filter out all arrows/bolts, filter out all explosive/gas/stamina/thawing/antidote potions. After that I'd like to slowly add some quality of life features like changing the name of all rare circlets with a big red X infront of that name, but the first thing is way more important to me. I want to be sure that some items arent filtered out from the game. Would be very shitty to find out that high runes or other rare items have been filtered out the whole time. Thanks guys!

Edit: In case it helps the current program i use is "BH 1.5s" (under the reddit link its the "1.5s - 1.13c only")
And my config looks like this:

```
    //Slippitty's Config v3.3 lite for BH v0.1.5s
//About Config: https://github.com/slippittydo/bh-config
//Update URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slippittydo/bh-config/master/1.5s/full/BH.cfg
//Shoutout to underbent for updates of BH and a great wiki
//Item Codes can be found here:
//https://github.com/dkuwahara/OmegaBot/blob/master/data/item_data.txt

//mHax Configuration File

//Maphack Configuration
Missile Color[Player]:   0x97
Missile Color[Neutral]:  0x0A
Missile Color[Partied]:  0x84
Missile Color[Hostile]:  0x5B

Monster Color[Normal]:   0x5B
Monster Color[Minion]:   0x60
Monster Color[Champion]: 0x91
Monster Color[Boss]:     0x84

Reveal Map:     False, None
Show Monsters:      False, None
Show Missiles:      False, None
Force Light Radius: False, None
Remove Weather:     False, None
Infravision:        False, None
Remove Shake:       True, None
Display Level Names:    True, None
RevealMode:     1

//Skill Warnings: set true to warn when effect expires from the player
//The effect numbers can be found here:
//https://github.com/underbent/slashdiablo-maphack/wiki/Effects
Skill Warning[16]:  False       // enchant
Skill Warning[32]:  False       // battle orders
Skill Warning[101]: False       // holy shield
Skill Warning[149]: False       // oak sage
Skill Warning[151]: False       // cyclone armor

//Screen Info Configuration
AutomapInfo[0]:     Game Name: %GAMENAME%
AutomapInfo[1]:     Game Password: %GAMEPASS%
AutomapInfo[2]:     %LEVEL%
AutomapInfo[3]:     Difficulty: %GAMEDIFF%
AutomapInfo[4]:     Ip: %GAMEIP%
AutomapInfo[5]:     %GAMETIME%
AutomapInfo[6]:     %REALTIME%

//Quest Drop Warning for Mephisto/Diablo/Baal quests
Quest Drop Warning: False

//Gamefilter Configuration
GameListRefresh:    1500

//Bnet Configuration
Show Last Game:     False
Fail To Join:       4000

//Character Configuration
Character Stats:    VK_8

//Item Configuration
Show Ethereal:      True, None
Show Sockets:       True, None
Show iLvl:      False, None
Show Rune Numbers:  False, None
Alt Item Style:     True, None
Color Mod:      False, None
Shorten Item Names: False, None
Show Players Gear:  VK_0

//AutoTele Configuration
Display Messages:   False, None
Draw Path:      False, None
Draw Destination:   False, None
CP to cave:     False, None
Fast Teleport:      False, None

Next Tele:      VK_NUMPAD0
Other Tele:     VK_NUMPAD1
Waypoint Tele:      VK_NUMPAD2
Prev Tele:      VK_NUMPAD3

Path Color:     97
Next Color:     0x97
Other Color:        0x0A
WP Color:       0x84
Prev Color:     0x5B

//Party Configuration
Party Enabled:      False, VK_9
Looting Enabled:    False, VK_7

//Using Potions in Inventory
Use Healing Potion: False, VK_NUMPADMULTIPLY
Use Mana Potion:    False, VK_NUMPADSUBTRACT

//Spam Filter Configuration
Log Chat:       False, None
Log Blocks:     False, None
Enabled:        False, None
Autosave:       False, None
Log File:       chatlog.txt
Update URL:     
Token DB:       tokens.db

//Item Display Configuration
Advanced Item Display:  True, None

//Dangerous Monsters
//Gloams, Dolls & Nith Vipers
Monster Color[118]:      0x9B
Monster Color[119]:      0x9B
Monster Color[120]:      0x9B
Monster Color[121]:      0x9B
Monster Color[212]:      0x9B
Monster Color[213]:      0x9B
Monster Color[214]:      0x9B
Monster Color[215]:      0x9B
Monster Color[216]:      0x9B
Monster Color[597]:      0x9B
Monster Color[639]:      0x9B
Monster Color[640]:      0x9B
Monster Color[641]:      0x9B
Monster Color[690]:      0x9B
Monster Color[691]:      0x9B
Monster Color[733]:      0x9B

// GEMS
// Indicators: Colour coded (eg. Purple for Amethysts)

ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=1]: %PURPLE%o %WHITE%%GEMLEVEL%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=2]: o %GEMLEVEL%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=3]: %GREEN%o %WHITE%%GEMLEVEL%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=4]: %RED%o %WHITE%%GEMLEVEL%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=5]: %BLUE%o %WHITE%%GEMLEVEL%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=6]: %YELLOW%o %WHITE%%GEMLEVEL%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=7]: %GRAY%o %WHITE%%GEMLEVEL%

//Optional - Add map indicators for flawless gems.
//ItemDisplay[GEMLEVEL=4]: %BLUE%%MAP%

//RUNES
//El -> Fal: Grey Indicator, Orange text, no map icon
//Lem -> Gul: Red Indicator, Orange text, red map icon
//Vex -> Zod: Purple Indicator, Orange text, purple map icon

ItemDisplay[RUNE<20]: %GRAY%0 %ORANGE%%RUNENAME% Rune (%RUNENUM%)
ItemDisplay[RUNE>25]: %PURPLE%0%MAP% %ORANGE%%RUNENAME% Rune (%RUNENUM%)
ItemDisplay[RUNE>19]: %RED%0%MAP% %ORANGE%%RUNENAME% Rune (%RUNENUM%)

//Add Indicators
//Indicators: Grey (Normal), Red (Exceptional), Purple (Elite)

//Uniques
ItemDisplay[UNI NORM]: %GRAY%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[UNI EXC]: %RED%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[UNI ELT]: %PURPLE%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[UNI (rin OR amu OR jew)]: %PURPLE%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%

//Set Items
ItemDisplay[SET NORM]: %GRAY%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET EXC]: %RED%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET ELT]: %PURPLE%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET rin]: %GRAY%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET amu]: %PURPLE%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%

//Add ethereality, sockets, ilvl to the name
ItemDisplay[ETH]: %NAME% (Eth)%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SOCK>0]: %NAME% (%SOCKETS%)%CONTINUE%
//ItemDisplay[]: %NAME% [L%ILVL%] %CONTINUE%

//Optional Customization Section
//Add custom shit here or don't


//End customization

//Minimap Socketables

//Runewords
ItemDisplay[RW]: %NAME%%MAP%

//Wirt's Leg
ItemDisplay[leg]: %NAME%

//4k Fort Base
ItemDisplay[NMAG DEF>1328 ETH !RW SOCK=4 !SUP EQ2]: %RED%0 %PURPLE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Ebug Bases >750 Defense
ItemDisplay[NMAG ETH DEF>750 SOCK=0 !SUP EQ2]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Elite Eth Infinity/Insight Bases
ItemDisplay[NMAG ETH SOCK=0 !SUP  ELT WP8 !7vo !7o7]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[NMAG ETH SOCK=4 ELT WP8 !7vo !7o7]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//+3 BO Barb Hats
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH ILVL>25 SK149>2 !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2 CL2]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Paladin Shields >39@ non-eth, >29@ Eth
ItemDisplay[NMAG ETH RES>29 SOCK=0 !SUP ELT CL3]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH RES>39 (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=4) ELT CL3]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH RES>39 (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=4) CL3]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%

//Superior Enigma & COH Bases
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>14 !ETH !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2 xtp]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH (ED>9 SOCK=3 OR ED>14 !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2) uui]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH (ED>9 SOCK=3 OR ED>14 !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2) utp]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//15ed Monarch Spirit
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>14 !ETH !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2 !SOCK=3 uit]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Chaos Bases
//Mind Blast + 3LS
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH (SK273>0 AND SK271>2) (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=3) (9tw OR 7tw)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Fade + 3Venom
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH (SK267>0 AND SK278>2) (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=3) (9tw OR 7tw OR 9lw OR 7lw)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Weapon Block + 3Venom
ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH (SK263>0 AND SK278>2) (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=3) (9tw OR 7tw OR 9lw OR 7lw)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Faith Bases
ItemDisplay[NMAG SOCK=4 TABSK0>2 (amc OR amb)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>14 SOCK=4 (6cb OR 6s7)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Berserker Axe/Colossus Sword/Blade Oath Bases 10+ ED
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>9 ETH SOCK=4 (7wa OR 7fb OR 7gd)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Berserker Axe/Colossus Sword/Blade Death Bases 10+ ED
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>9 ETH (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=5) (7wa OR 7fb OR 7gd)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Berserker Axe/Colossus Blade BotD Bases 10+ ED
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>9 ETH SOCK=6 (7wa OR 7gd)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//EBotD War Pike/GPA
ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>9 ETH (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=6) (7p7 OR 7h7)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//FoH Sticks
ItemDisplay[NMAG (SK121>2 AND SK123>2) (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=5) (wsp OR 9ws OR 7ws)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Holy Shield CTA
ItemDisplay[NMAG SK117>0 (SOCK=0 OR SOCK=5) (wsp OR 9ws OR 7ws)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//White Base +3 Spirit and +3 Spear  
ItemDisplay[NMAG (SK84>2 AND SK93>2) !SOCK=1 WP12 !wnd !ywn !9wn]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Optional White Items

//Leaf Base: +3 Enchant
//ItemDisplay[NMAG SK52>2 SOCK=2 WP11]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Memory Base: +3 Energy Shield
//ItemDisplay[NMAG SK58>2 SOCK=4 WP11]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Staff CTA Base: +3 Energy Shield
//ItemDisplay[NMAG SK58>2 SOCK=5 WP11]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//0/4/5/6 Socket Eth Crystal Swords
//ItemDisplay[NMAG ETH !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2 !SOCK=3 crs]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//0/4/5 Socket Eth Flails
//ItemDisplay[NMAG ETH !SOCK=1 !SOCK=2 !SOCK=3 fla]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Insight Golem Bases
//ItemDisplay[NMAG SOCK=4 WP8]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Imbue Diadems
//ItemDisplay[NMAG !ETH SOCK=0 ci3]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//White Base 3spirit OR 3spear      
//ItemDisplay[NMAG (SK84>2 OR SK93>2) !SOCK=1 WP12 !wnd !ywn !9wn]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Gothic Plate Enigma Bases
//ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>14 SOCK=3 gth]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Merc Faith Bases
//ItemDisplay[NMAG ED>14 SOCK=0 (6cb OR 6hb)]: %RED%0 %WHITE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Magic Items

//Circlets
ItemDisplay[MAG !ETH !ID EQ7]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Monarchs
ItemDisplay[MAG !ETH !ID uit]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Barb Hats
ItemDisplay[MAG !ID CL2]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Sorc Orbs
ItemDisplay[MAG !ID CL6]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Zon Javas
ItemDisplay[MAG !ID (am5 OR ama OR amf)]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Assassin Claws
ItemDisplay[MAG !ETH !ID (9lw OR 9tw OR 7tw OR 7lw)]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%

//Gosu Magic Items
ItemDisplay[MAG FBR=30 SOCK=4 uit]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[MAG LIFE>80 SOCK=4 EQ2]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[MAG FHR=24 SOCK=4 EQ2]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[IAS=40 TABSK2=6 (am5 OR ama OR amf)]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[IAS=40 (TABSK2=3 AND CLSK0=2) (am5 OR ama OR amf)]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[(TABSK34>2 AND SK149>2) CL2]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[(TABSK48>2 AND SK271>2) CL5]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[(CLSK6>1 AND SK271>1) CL5]: %PURPLE%0 %NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[(TABSK48>1 AND SK271>1) CL5]: %PURPLE%0 %NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[(TABSK8>2 AND SK52>2 AND SK61>0) CL6]: %PURPLE%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[(TABSK8>2 AND SK52>2) CL6]: %PURPLE%0 %NAME%%MAP%

//Rare Items

//Rings, Amulets, Jewels, & Circlets
ItemDisplay[RARE (rin OR amu OR jew OR EQ7)]: %RED%0 %YELLOW%%NAME%%MAP%

//Gloves & Boots
ItemDisplay[RARE !ID (EQ4 OR EQ5)]: %RED%0 %YELLOW%%NAME%%MAP%

//Druid Pelts
ItemDisplay[RARE CL1 !ID]: %RED%0 %YELLOW%%NAME%%MAP%

//Amazon Javelins
ItemDisplay[(am5 OR ama OR amf) RARE !ID]: %RED%0 %YELLOW%%NAME%%MAP%

//Assassin Claws
ItemDisplay[(9lw OR 9tw OR 7tw OR 7lw) RARE !ID]: %RED%0 %YELLOW%%NAME%%MAP%

//ETH Berserker Axe, Colossus Sword, Colossus Blade & Crystal Sword Variants
ItemDisplay[RARE ETH !ID (wax OR 9wa OR 7wa OR crs OR 9cr OR flb OR 9fb OR 7fb OR gsd OR 9gd OR 7gd OR CL5)]: %RED%0 %YELLOW%%NAME%%MAP%

//Add map indicators for Unique and Set items.

//Unique Hats
ItemDisplay[UNI !ID urn]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI SOCK=2 urn]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ci3]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH usk]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI (xh9 OR uap OR uhm OR usk OR uh9 OR dra OR baa OR urn)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Body Armor
ItemDisplay[UNI !ETH !ID ILVL>86 uar]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI RES>19 uar]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI (xea OR uui OR upl OR uar)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH (xrs OR xhn OR xpl)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Shields
ItemDisplay[UNI (uit OR pa9 OR nea OR nef)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Gloves
ItemDisplay[UNI (uvg OR uhg)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Boots
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH uvb]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI (xvb OR xtb OR xhb OR uvb OR umb OR uhb)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Belts
ItemDisplay[UNI !ETH ulc]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH ulc]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI !ETH umc]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Weapons
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH !ID 7pa]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH 7pa SOCK=3]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH 7wa]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI (7gw OR obf)]: %NAME%%ORANGE%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI ETH (72a OR 7s8 OR 7b8 OR 7bk)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[UNI (7fl OR 6lw OR 7ws OR 9tw OR oba OR obc OR ama OR amf)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Misc Uniques
ItemDisplay[UNI (cm1 OR cm2 OR cm3 OR rin OR amu OR jew)]: %NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Set Equips
ItemDisplay[SET (urn OR paf OR 7ws OR uar OR uth OR amu OR ci3)]: %NAME%%GREEN%%MAP%

//Display small charms, grand charms and jewels on the map
ItemDisplay[(cm1 OR cm3 OR jew)]: %RED%0 %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[cm2]: %NAME%

//Uber Keys on the Map
ItemDisplay[(pk1 OR pk2 OR pk3)]: %RED%0 %ORANGE%%NAME%%GOLD%%MAP%

//Ignore 'junk' (Miscellaneous potions, quivers, etc.), potion, scroll renaming & gold piles below 5000.
ItemDisplay[GOLD<5000]:
ItemDisplay[tsc]: %GREEN%+ %WHITE%TP
ItemDisplay[isc]: %GREEN%+ %WHITE%ID
ItemDisplay[hp5]: %RED%+ %WHITE%Health
ItemDisplay[mp5]: %BLUE%+ %WHITE%Mana
ItemDisplay[rvl]: %PURPLE%+ %WHITE%Reg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out by myself and the help of friendly slashdiablo discord. So my answer is not exclusively for single player. The configuration should work for slashdiablo aswell.

Here is the configuration file I created to filter out all the junk with BH 1.5s on Diablo II LOD 1.13c (with D2SE Plugy).

```
//whoami's config v0.0.1 lite for BH v0.1.5s
//=======================================================================================================
//About Config: https://github.com/slippittydo/bh-config
//Update URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slippittydo/bh-config/master/1.5s/full/BH.cfg
//Shoutout to underbent for updates of BH and a great wiki
//Item Codes can be found here:
//https://github.com/dkuwahara/OmegaBot/blob/master/data/item_data.txt


//=======================================================================================================
//Maphack Configuration
//=======================================================================================================
Missile Color[Player]:   0x97
Missile Color[Neutral]:  0x0A
Missile Color[Partied]:  0x84
Missile Color[Hostile]:  0x5B

Monster Color[Normal]:   0x5B
Monster Color[Minion]:   0x60
Monster Color[Champion]: 0x91
Monster Color[Boss]:     0x84

Reveal Map:             False, None
Show Monsters:          False, None
Show Missiles:          False, None
Force Light Radius:     False, None
Remove Weather:         False, None
Infravision:            False, None
Remove Shake:           True, None
Display Level Names:    True, None
RevealMode:     1


//=======================================================================================================
//Skill Warnings
//=======================================================================================================
//Set true to warn when effect expires from the player
//The effect numbers can be found here:
//https://github.com/underbent/slashdiablo-maphack/wiki/Effects
Skill Warning[16]:  False         // enchant
Skill Warning[32]:  True          // battle orders
Skill Warning[101]: True          // holy shield
Skill Warning[149]: True          // oak sage
Skill Warning[151]: False         // cyclone armor

//Screen Info Configuration
AutomapInfo[0]:     Game Name: %GAMENAME%
AutomapInfo[1]:     Game Password: %GAMEPASS%
AutomapInfo[2]:     %LEVEL%
AutomapInfo[3]:     Difficulty: %GAMEDIFF%
AutomapInfo[4]:     Ip: %GAMEIP%
AutomapInfo[5]:     %GAMETIME%
AutomapInfo[6]:     %REALTIME%


//=======================================================================================================
//Quest Drop Warnings
//=======================================================================================================
//Quest Drop Warning for Mephisto/Diablo/Baal quests
Quest Drop Warning: False


//=======================================================================================================
//Bnet Config
//=======================================================================================================
//Gamefilter Configuration
GameListRefresh:    1500

//Bnet Configuration
Show Last Game:     False
Fail To Join:       4000

//Character Configuration
Character Stats:    VK_8

//Party Configuration
Party Enabled:      False, VK_9
Looting Enabled:    False, VK_7


//=======================================================================================================
//Item Config
//=======================================================================================================
Show Ethereal:      True, None
Show Sockets:       True, None
Show iLvl:      False, None
Show Rune Numbers:  True, None
Alt Item Style:     False, None
Color Mod:      False, None
Shorten Item Names: False, None
Show Players Gear:  VK_0


//=======================================================================================================
//Autotele Config
//=======================================================================================================
Display Messages:   False, None
Draw Path:      False, None
Draw Destination:   False, None
CP to cave:     False, None
Fast Teleport:      False, None

Next Tele:      VK_NUMPAD0
Other Tele:     VK_NUMPAD1
Waypoint Tele:      VK_NUMPAD2
Prev Tele:      VK_NUMPAD3

Path Color:     97
Next Color:     0x97
Other Color:    0x0A
WP Color:       0x84
Prev Color:     0x5B


//=======================================================================================================
//Using Potions in Inventory
//=======================================================================================================
Use Healing Potion: False, VK_NUMPADMULTIPLY
Use Mana Potion:    False, VK_NUMPADSUBTRACT


//=======================================================================================================
//Spam Filter Configuration
//=======================================================================================================
Log Chat:       False, None
Log Blocks:     False, None
Enabled:        False, None
Autosave:       False, None
Log File:       chatlog.txt
Update URL:     
Token DB:       tokens.db


//=======================================================================================================
//Item Display Configuration
//=======================================================================================================
Advanced Item Display:  True, None


//=======================================================================================================
//Dangerous Monsters
//=======================================================================================================
//Gloams, Dolls & Nith Vipers
Monster Color[118]:      0x9B
Monster Color[119]:      0x9B
Monster Color[120]:      0x9B
Monster Color[121]:      0x9B
Monster Color[212]:      0x9B
Monster Color[213]:      0x9B
Monster Color[214]:      0x9B
Monster Color[215]:      0x9B
Monster Color[216]:      0x9B
Monster Color[597]:      0x9B
Monster Color[639]:      0x9B
Monster Color[640]:      0x9B
Monster Color[641]:      0x9B
Monster Color[690]:      0x9B
Monster Color[691]:      0x9B
Monster Color[733]:      0x9B





//#######################################################################################################
//DROPFILTER
//#######################################################################################################

//=======================================================================================================
//INDICATORS
//=======================================================================================================
//Add Indicators
//Indicators: Grey (Normal), Red (Exceptional), Purple (Elite)

//Uniques
ItemDisplay[UNI NORM]: %GRAY%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[UNI EXC]: %RED%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[UNI ELT]: %PURPLE%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[UNI (rin OR amu OR jew)]: %PURPLE%0 %GOLD%%NAME%%CONTINUE%

//Set Items
ItemDisplay[SET NORM]: %GRAY%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET EXC]: %RED%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET ELT]: %PURPLE%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET rin]: %GRAY%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SET amu]: %PURPLE%0 %GREEN%%NAME%%CONTINUE%

//Add ethereality, sockets, ilvl to the name
ItemDisplay[ETH]: %NAME% (Eth)%CONTINUE%
ItemDisplay[SOCK>0]: %NAME% (%SOCKETS%)%CONTINUE%
//ItemDisplay[]: %NAME% [L%ILVL%] %CONTINUE%


//=======================================================================================================
// GEMS
//=======================================================================================================
// Indicators: Colour coded (eg. Purple for Amethysts)
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=1]: %PURPLE%G %WHITE%%NAME%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=2]: %WHITE%G %NAME%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=3]: %GREEN%G %WHITE%%NAME%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=4]: %RED%G %WHITE%%NAME%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=5]: %BLUE%G %WHITE%%NAME%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=6]: %YELLOW%G %WHITE%%NAME%
ItemDisplay[GEMTYPE=7]: %GRAY%G %WHITE%%NAME%


//=======================================================================================================
// CHARMS & JEWELS
//=======================================================================================================
ItemDisplay[(cm1 OR cm3)]: %RED%oo %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%
ItemDisplay[cm2 OR jew]: %RED%o %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%


//=======================================================================================================
// JUNK
//=======================================================================================================
//Ignore 'junk' (Miscellaneous potions, quivers, etc.), potion, scroll renaming & gold piles below 5000.
ItemDisplay[GOLD<3000]:
ItemDisplay[tsc]: %GREEN%* %WHITE%TP
ItemDisplay[isc]: %GREEN%* %WHITE%ID
ItemDisplay[hp5]: %RED%* %WHITE%Health
ItemDisplay[mp5]: %BLUE%* %WHITE%Mana
ItemDisplay[rvl]: %PURPLE%* %WHITE%Reg
ItemDisplay[rvs]:
ItemDisplay[hp4]:
ItemDisplay[hp3]:
ItemDisplay[hp2]:
ItemDisplay[hp1]:
ItemDisplay[mp4]:
ItemDisplay[mp3]:
ItemDisplay[mp2]:
ItemDisplay[mp1]:
ItemDisplay[aqv]:
ItemDisplay[cqv]://%WHITE%Bolts
ItemDisplay[key]://%WHITE%Key
ItemDisplay[vps]://Stamina
ItemDisplay[yps]: %GREEN%* %WHITE%Antidote
ItemDisplay[wms]://Thawing potion
ItemDisplay[gps]://Ignore Rancid Gas potion
ItemDisplay[ops]://Ignore Oil potion
ItemDisplay[gpm]://Ignore Choking Gas potion
ItemDisplay[opm]://Ignore Exploding potion
ItemDisplay[gpl]://Ignore Strangling Gas potion
ItemDisplay[opl]://Ignore Fulminating potion

//Optional - Add map indicators for flawless gems.
//ItemDisplay[GEMLEVEL=4]: %BLUE%%MAP%

//=======================================================================================================
//RUNES
//=======================================================================================================
//El -> Fal: Grey Indicator, Orange text, no map icon
//Lem -> Gul: Red Indicator, Orange text, red map icon
//Vex -> Zod: Purple Indicator, Orange text, purple map icon

ItemDisplay[RUNE<20]: %GRAY%0 %ORANGE%%RUNENAME% Rune (%RUNENUM%)
ItemDisplay[RUNE>25]: %PURPLE%0%MAP% %ORANGE%GG! %RUNENAME% Rune (%RUNENUM%)
ItemDisplay[RUNE>19]: %RED%0%MAP% %ORANGE%%RUNENAME% Rune (%RUNENUM%)
```

The important setting for the item filter is:

```
Advanced Item Display:  True, None
```

Under the Junk section you can find all the commands that disable the items from beeing viewed in game. The command is:

```
ItemDisplay[<<Itemcode>>]:
```

If you don't write anything after the ":", it means that the item gets disabled. The aqv itemcode stands for arrows for example. So this means that arrows are not going to be seen by the player.

The command "ItemDisplay[GOLD<3000]:" means that gold piles that are smaller than 3000 won't be shown to the player.

Regarding the quality of life feature to highlight specific items, you can find an example under the charms section.

```
ItemDisplay[(cm1 OR cm3)]: %RED%oo %BLUE%%NAME%%MAP%
```

This command means that small charms and giant charms are going to be viewed with two red o symbols and the name of the charm after (in blue). The map command means that there will be a small rectangle on the minimap to highlight the item on the minimap aswell.

All the itemcodes can be found on github https://github.com/dkuwahara/OmegaBot/blob/master/data/item_data.txt

```
    Cap|cap|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Skull Cap|skp|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Helm|hlm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Full Helm|fhl|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Great Helm|ghm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Crown|crn|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Mask|msk|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Quilted Armor|qui|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Leather Armor|lea|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Hard Leather Armor|hla|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Studded Leather|stu|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Ring Mail|rng|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Scale Mail|scl|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Chain Mail|chn|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Breast Plate|brs|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Splint Mail|spl|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Plate Mail|plt|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Field Plate|fld|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Gothic Plate|gth|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Full Plate Mail|ful|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Ancient Armor|aar|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Light Plate|ltp|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Buckler|buc|Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Small Shield|sml|Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Large Shield|lrg|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Kite Shield|kit|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Tower Shield|tow|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Gothic Shield|gts|Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Leather Gloves|lgl|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Heavy Gloves|vgl|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Chain Gloves|mgl|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Light Gauntlets|tgl|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Gauntlets|hgl|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Boots|lbt|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Heavy Boots|vbt|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Chain Boots|mbt|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Light Plated Boots|tbt|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Greaves|hbt|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Sash|lbl|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Light Belt|vbl|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Belt|mbl|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Heavy Belt|tbl|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Plated Belt|hbl|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Bone Helm|bhm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Bone Shield|bsh|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Spiked Shield|spk|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
War Hat|xap|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Sallet|xkp|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Casque|xlm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Basinet|xhl|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Winged Helm|xhm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Grand Crown|xrn|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Death Mask|xsk|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Ghost Armor|xui|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Serpentskin Armor|xea|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Demonhide Armor|xla|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Trellised Armor|xtu|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Linked Mail|xng|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Tigulated Mail|xcl|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Mesh Armor|xhn|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Cuirass|xrs|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Russet Armor|xpl|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Templar Coat|xlt|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Sharktooth Armor|xld|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Embossed Plate|xth|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Chaos Armor|xul|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Ornate Plate|xar|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Mage Plate|xtp|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Defender|xuc|Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Round Shield|xml|Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Scutum|xrg|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Dragon Shield|xit|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Pavise|xow|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Ancient Shield|xts|Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Demonhide Gloves|xlg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Sharkskin Gloves|xvg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Heavy Bracers|xmg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Battle Gauntlets|xtg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
War Gauntlets|xhg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Demonhide Boots|xlb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Sharkskin Boots|xvb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Mesh Boots|xmb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Battle Boots|xtb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
War Boots|xhb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Demonhide Sash|zlb|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Sharkskin Belt|zvb|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Mesh Belt|zmb|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Battle Belt|ztb|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
War Belt|zhb|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Grim Helm|xh9|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Grim Shield|xsh|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Barbed Shield|xpk|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Wolf Head|dr1|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Hawk Helm|dr2|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Antlers|dr3|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Falcon Mask|dr4|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Spirit Mask|dr5|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Jawbone Cap|ba1|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Fanged Helm|ba2|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Horned Helm|ba3|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Assault Helmet|ba4|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Avenger Guard|ba5|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Targe|pa1|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Rondache|pa2|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Heraldic Shield|pa3|Paladin Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Aerin Shield|pa4|Paladin Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Crown Shield|pa5|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Preserved Head|ne1|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Zombie Head|ne2|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Unraveller Head|ne3|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Gargoyle Head|ne4|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Demon Head|ne5|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Circlet|ci0|Circlet|2|2|0|0|0
Coronet|ci1|Circlet|2|2|0|0|0
Tiara|ci2|Circlet|2|2|0|0|0
Diadem|ci3|Circlet|2|2|0|0|0
Shako|uap|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Hydraskull|ukp|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Armet|ulm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Giant Conch|uhl|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Spired Helm|uhm|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Corona|urn|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Demonhead|usk|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Dusk Shroud|uui|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Wyrmhide|uea|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Scarab Husk|ula|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Wire Fleece|utu|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Diamond Mail|ung|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Loricated Mail|ucl|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Boneweave|uhn|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Great Hauberk|urs|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Balrog Skin|upl|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Hellforge Plate|ult|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Kraken Shell|uld|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Lacquered Plate|uth|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Shadow Plate|uul|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Sacred Armor|uar|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Archon Plate|utp|Armor|2|3|0|0|0
Heater|uuc|Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Luna|uml|Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Hyperion|urg|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Monarch|uit|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Aegis|uow|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Ward|uts|Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Bramble Mitts|ulg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Vampirebone Gloves|uvg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Vambraces|umg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Crusader Gauntlets|utg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Ogre Gauntlets|uhg|Gloves|2|2|0|0|0
Wyrmhide Boots|ulb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Scarabshell Boots|uvb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Boneweave Boots|umb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Mirrored Boots|utb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Myrmidon Greaves|uhb|Boots|2|2|0|0|0
Spiderweb Sash|ulc|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Vampirefang Belt|uvc|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Mithril Coil|umc|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Troll Belt|utc|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Colossus Girdle|uhc|Belt|2|1|0|0|0
Bone Visage|uh9|Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Troll Nest|ush|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Blade Barrier|upk|Shield|2|3|0|0|0
Alpha Helm|dr6|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Griffon Headdress|dr7|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Hunter's Guise|dr8|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Sacred Feathers|dr9|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Totemic Mask|dra|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Jawbone Visor|ba6|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Lion Helm|ba7|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Rage Mask|ba8|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Savage Helmet|ba9|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Slayer Guard|baa|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Akaran Targe|pa6|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Akaran Rondache|pa7|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Protector Shield|pa8|Paladin Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Gilded Shield|pa9|Paladin Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Royal Shield|paa|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Mummified Trophy|ne6|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Fetish Trophy|ne7|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Sexton Trophy|ne8|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Cantor Trophy|ne9|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Hierophant Trophy|nea|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Blood Spirit|drb|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Sun Spirit|drc|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Earth Spirit|drd|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Sky Spirit|dre|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Dream Spirit|drf|Druid Pelt|2|2|0|0|0
Carnage Helm|bab|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Fury Visor|bac|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Destroyer Helm|bad|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Conqueror Crown|bae|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Guardian Crown|baf|Barbarian Helm|2|2|0|0|0
Sacred Targe|pab|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Sacred Rondache|pac|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Kurast Shield|pad|Paladin Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Zakarum Shield|pae|Paladin Shield|2|4|0|0|0
Vortex Shield|paf|Paladin Shield|2|2|0|0|0
Minion Skull|neb|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Hellspawn Skull|neg|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Overseer Skull|ned|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Succubus Skull|nee|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Bloodlord Skull|nef|Necromancer Shrunken Head|2|2|0|0|0
Elixir|elx|Elixir|1|1|0|1|0
hpo|hpo|Health Potion|1|1|0|1|0
mpo|mpo|Mana Potion|1|1|0|1|0
hpf|hpf|Health Potion|1|1|0|1|0
mpf|mpf|Mana Potion|1|1|0|1|0
Stamina Potion|vps|Stamina Potion|1|1|0|1|0
Antidote Potion|yps|Antidote Potion|1|1|0|1|0
Rejuvenation Potion|rvs|Rejuvenation Potion|1|1|0|1|0
Full Rejuvenation Potion|rvl|Rejuvenation Potion|1|1|0|1|0
Thawing Potion|wms|Thawing Potion|1|1|0|1|0
Tome of Town Portal|tbk|Tome|1|2|1|1|0
Tome of Identify|ibk|Tome|1|2|1|1|0
Amulet|amu|Amulet|1|1|0|0|0
Top of the Horadric Staff|vip|Amulet|1|1|0|0|0
Ring|rin|Ring|1|1|0|0|0
Gold|gld|Gold|1|1|1|0|0
Scroll of Inifuss|bks|Quest Item|2|2|0|0|0
Key to the Cairn Stones|bkd|Quest Item|2|2|0|0|0
Arrows|aqv|Arrows|1|3|1|0|0
Torch|tch|Torch|1|2|0|0|0
Bolts|cqv|Bolts|1|3|1|0|0
Scroll of Town Portal|tsc|Scroll|1|1|0|1|0
Scroll of Identify|isc|Scroll|1|1|0|1|0
Heart|hrt|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Brain|brz|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Jawbone|jaw|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Eye|eyz|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Horn|hrn|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Tail|tal|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Flag|flg|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Fang|fng|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Quill|qll|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Soul|sol|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Scalp|scz|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Spleen|spe|Body Part|1|1|0|0|0
Key|key|Key|1|1|1|0|0
The Black Tower Key|luv|Key|1|2|0|0|0
Potion of Life|xyz|Quest Item|1|1|0|1|0
A Jade Figurine|j34|Quest Item|1|2|0|0|0
The Golden Bird|g34|Quest Item|1|2|0|0|0
Lam Esen's Tome|bbb|Quest Item|2|2|0|0|0
Horadric Cube|box|Quest Item|2|2|0|1|0
Horadric Scroll|tr1|Quest Item|2|2|0|0|0
Mephisto's Soulstone|mss|Quest Item|1|1|0|0|0
Book of Skill|ass|Quest Item|2|2|0|1|0
Khalim's Eye|qey|Quest Item|1|1|0|0|0
Khalim's Heart|qhr|Quest Item|1|1|0|0|0
Khalim's Brain|qbr|Quest Item|1|1|0|0|0
Ear|ear|Ear|1|1|0|0|0
Chipped Amethyst|gcv|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawed Amethyst|gfv|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Amethyst|gsv|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawless Amethyst|gzv|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Perfect Amethyst|gpv|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Chipped Topaz|gcy|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawed Topaz|gfy|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Topaz|gsy|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawless Topaz|gly|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Perfect Topaz|gpy|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Chipped Sapphire|gcb|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawed Sapphire|gfb|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Sapphire|gsb|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawless Sapphire|glb|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Perfect Sapphire|gpb|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Chipped Emerald|gcg|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawed Emerald|gfg|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Emerald|gsg|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawless Emerald|glg|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Perfect Emerald|gpg|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Chipped Ruby|gcr|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Flawed Ruby|gfr|Gem|1|1|0|0|0
Ruby|gsr|Gem|1|1|0|0|0 [ ... ]
```

Comment: If this is sufficient to answer your own question, be sure to mark it as answered also

Comment: can be marked after 2 days